# How to access full request information in a RAD Studio Web Server application?

Tags: c++builder, rad-studio

i am new to RAD studio C++, so please don't mind if i ask very basic questions here.

I have created a "Web Server application" (GUI standalone) from the RAD Studio project templates.
This gives me a "WebModule" with related .cpp and .h file. I have added actions to the WebModule (might be called "endpoints" as well and those are called when i send requests to the WebServer. This works fine.

For example on GET request, this method gets called:

```
void __fastcall TWebModule1::WebModule1WebActionItem2Action(TObject *Sender, TWebRequest *Request,
          TWebResponse *Response, bool &Handled)
{
        /* On Get Action */
        /* How to retrieve the request informations ?? */
    Response->Content =
    "<html>"
    "<head><title>Web Server Application</title></head>"
    "<body>Action 2: CALLED</body>"
    "</html>";
}
```

However, in the method itself i can not access the request data such as URL. Is there something i am missing or is this because the "WebDispatcher" has already deleted the URL from the request?

In addition, is there any option to instantiate a "WebModule" directly in the source code rather than dragging and dropping and editing a design element?

I have viewed the References on the Embarcadero site for the classes used in the example, but i must admit that it does not answer my question in a way that i understand.

I'd be glad if someone could point me to a specific example/ documentation page or give a hint what i can try.

Thanks a lot and kind regards

What i did was
-Created a webserver project
-added some "WebActionItem" to the "WebModule" by using the IDEs "design tool"
-ran the application in debug mode and tried to access fields of the "WebRequest"

-> URL property of "TWebRequest *Request" (see code above) for example is empty.